# How is JIT compiled code injected in memory and executed?

Tags: .net, clr, jit

> "Consider a typical Windows x86 or
> AMD64 architecture, the memory is
> divided in executable sections that
> cannot be written to and data sections
> that can be written to but cannot be
> executed (think DEP)."
>
> "JIT compiles methods in-memory, does
> (generally) not store anything to
> disk, instead moves it around where
> the next instruction pointer can reach
> it, changes the current instruction
> pointer (pointing to the JIT) to point
> to the newly generated code and then
> executes it."

These two paragraphs, while a bit over-simplified, are what I basically understand of JIT and Windows' memory model. I also know that when I try to copy some executable code in memory by hand and try to execute it, I will generally be unable to do it (unless with DLL injection).

How did the JIT-designers overcome this hurdle? Do they use a ring-0 driver or is everything done in user mode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is simply done with the Windows VirtualProtect() API function.  It changes the virtual memory page attributes.  From PAGE_READWRITE so the JIT compiler can write the machine code to PAGE_EXECUTE_READ so it can be executed.  No special privileges are required to do so since the page is owned by the process that also runs the JIT compiler.

Comment: Really, *that* simple? Makes sense. (OT) Ah, I remember, last time I needed to inject something it was not in my own process (i.e., to delete the current running executable you need to first unload the executable, typical chicken / egg problem).

Comment: @Hans: reading further about it, I wonder how that relates to this [Social MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/2a043d8c-3ac4-4b3d-9837-0bfe8e7d6788), explaining you need Admin rights to use `VirtualProtect` to change the flag and claiming it can't work that way. With ActionScript, the same principle works with `VirtualAlloc`, [as apparently shown by this blogger](http://null.co.in/2010/04/29/spraying-just-in-time/) (he gets the names wrong, see subscript to his 3rd image). Both posts let me assume it'd be `VirtualAlloc` instead. What are your thoughts here?

Comment: @Abel: looks familiar.  No, I noted in that post that admin rights were not needed.  The OP agreed.

Comment: @Hans: yes, I reacted to quick. Looking through [`VirtualProtect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898%28VS.85%29.aspx) there's no mention of this either. Note that in SSCLI I didn't find VirtualProtect used in fjitcompiler.cpp, only VirtualAlloc. VirtualProtect was redefined/undefined often in hosting.cpp (into `Dont_Use_VirtualProtect` lol). Finally, it seems to come down to a call to [`IHostMemoryManager->VirtualProtect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164513.aspx), if available, else `::VirtualProtect` (the Win32 API) is called (which is what you said)

Comment: PS: sorry I dragged on about this, but I needed some reassurance. Fortunately you gave enough an answer to research further on the subject. Thanks!

Comment: It's there, clr\src\utilcode\hostimpl.cpp, ClrVirtualProtect() method.

Comment: @Hans: Would you happen to know whether the CLR JIT actually does remove write access to the pages containing generated code when compilation finishes?  Or are they left with `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` access?